# Image Sequence no longer plays audio or png images after render

Tags: image, audio

I'm trying to fix an issue I'm having with Blender's Image Sequence. After compiling my images, audio and visuals I rendered the file however when I go back to the file, nothing is playing as it should, aside from the first 5 seconds. The PNGs are no longer visible and the audio that I recorded (not from the YouTube videos) can no longer be heard. AI apologize if I'm lacking information here but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you

P.S.
Somehow my FPS was also bumped up to 33.33...not sure how this happened.

Comment: Hello, are you sure that the PNGs are still in their folder?

Comment: Yes I checked the folder and they are still there.

Comment: I looked again and remembered I placed them in a sub folder. I just put them back so the directories match. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Anon ... Is this problem solved, without need for a full answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the PNGs are in the good folder, otherwise Blender won't find them, or reimport them from your new folder.